# How to use/call other modules to Implement own NAND gate?

Tags: verilog

I want to write my own `NAND_GATE` using my own `AND_GATE` module:

```
module and_gate(input a, input b, output out);
    assign out = a & b;
endmodule
```

**Method 1**

What I came up with:

```
module nand_gate(input a, input b, output out);
    assign out = and_gate(a, b);
endmodule
```

But I think this is wrong, because I can't call modules like functions with return values in other programming langues, right?

**Method 2**

So I thought about something like this:

```
module nand_gate(input a, input b, output out);
    assign out = and_gate(a, b, ~out);
endmodule
```

But I don't know if it that's right either?

**Method 3**

Another idea I had was something like this:

```
module nand_gate(input a, input b, output out);
    wire temp;
    assign temp = and_gate(a, b, out);
    assign out = ~temp;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close:

```
module nand_gate(input a, input b, output out);
    wire temp;
    and_gate i0 (
        .a      (a),
        .b      (b),
        .out    (temp)
    );
    assign out = ~temp;
endmodule
```

A module does not have a return value, which is why you can't assign a module to a signal.

You need an instance name; I arbitrarily chose `i0`.

The verbose port connections I used are optional, but it is a good practice.